Bearing directly on integrated crown race?
In my Lapierre Aircode frameset, I got an acros headset set with two dust covers. I don't know if one is a spare. The steerer tube has an integrated crownrace. Do I sit the bearing directly onto the integrated crownrace or do I put in the dust cover between the intergrated crownrace and the bearing, which makes it a little less snug, as the dust cover does not align perfectly with the bearing. On the otherside the dust cover would be a nice addition to hold of the dirt coming in from bottom of the headtube.

Welcome to Bicycle Stack Exchange!
Are you certain one of the "dust covers" is not a centering sleeve for the upper headset?  Here is the headset section at Acros Components website.  When you navigate this section of the Acros website, several bike brands are listed so that you can find the specific headset for your bike make and model. Within the Lapierre brand, however, the Aircode model is not listed. I can see that of the four or five models they do list, that they all require integrated headsets for 52mm headtubes both upper and lower. This would be IS52/28.7 | IS52/40 in the Standardized Headset Identification System (SHIS) parlance.
At any rate, looking at the Acros IS offerings, I can see some, at least, have a rather substantial centering sleeve.  Centering sleeves are used in the upper headset on top of the bearing to help keep the steerer tube centered in the system as well as transferring the top cap's force in preloading the bearings when a threadless headset system is installed.
Another possibility is mistaking a crown race that has a sealing material bonded to it as a dust cover. That is essentially what it is albeit for the lower headset as today's crown races are pretty much just seats for the sealed cartridge bearings often used today.  Acros crown races do have a sealing material "vulcanized" (using the term the Acros website uses in their description) to their crown races.  Presumably, since you state you acquired a Lapierre Frameset, which may or may not have come with a fork, the headset provided included one of these fringed crown races in case the chosen fork was not one with an integrated crown race and thus would've required
the crown race (typically) provided with a complete headset.
I encourage you to contact Acros (there's prominent links in their website to do this) with your bike information and they'll certainly clear up what you have there and how it should be used.
